# C# data not saving to internal mdf database

Tags: c#, database, csv, datagridview, mdf

I am using an internal .mdf database that I want to store data that I am reading from a CSV and displaying into a data grid view. I have tried everything and cannot get the database to update properly. The data reads properly into the datagridview but when i close out of the form and re-open it the data doesnt populate back in the datagridview. So how do I push the changes from the datagridview back to the mdf database?

```
   private void btnOpenFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream myStream = null;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV Files|*.csv";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            try
            {
                if ((myStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
                {
                    string strFileName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    string[] strLines = File.ReadAllLines(strFileName);
                    string[] strFields;

                    strFields = strLines[0].Split(new char[] { ',' });

                    int intCols = 1;

                    DataTable dt = dsetPCInfo.tblPCInfo;

                    for (int intL = 1; intL < strLines.GetLength(0); intL++)
                    {

                        strFields = strLines[intL].Split(new char[] { ',' });
                        DataRow Row;

                        Row = dt.NewRow();
                        for (int f = 0; f < intCols; f++)

                            Row[f] = strFields[f];
                            dt.Rows.Add(Row);

                        tblPCInfoTableAdapter.Update(dsetPCInfo.tblPCInfo);

                    }

                    dgvPCInfo.DataSource = dsetPCInfo.tblPCInfo;

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: Could not read file from disk. Original error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void frmPCInfo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'dsetPCInfo.tblPCInfo' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        //dgvPCInfo.DataSource = dsetPCInfo.tblPCInfo;


    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Validate();
            this.tblPCInfoBindingSource.EndEdit();
            this.tblPCInfoTableAdapter.Update(this.dsetPCInfo.tblPCInfo);
            dsetPCInfo.tblPCInfo.AcceptChanges();
            MessageBox.Show("Update Successful");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Update failed");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you share your connection string?

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename="F:\BPA\Visual Studios Projects\IS Task\IS Systems Monitor\IS Systems Monitor\dbPCInfo.mdf";Integrated Security=True

Comment: I will say that this is my first time creating an internal database and learning as I go. I linked the dataset to the database and are using a tableadapter